# How to remove tabs from customer section in Magento admin without using xml?

Tags: magento

I am using following code to remove the addresses tab from the admin customer section.

**config.xml**

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>    
            <customer_edit_tabs>Muk_CustomRole_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs</customer_edit_tabs>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

**override file**

```
class Muk_CustomRole_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs
{
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        parent::_beforeToHtml();
        $this->removeTab('addresses');        
        $this->_updateActiveTab();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

But I am not getting success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Muk_CustomRole_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tabs
{
  public function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        parent::_beforeToHtml();
        $this->removeTab('addresses');
        $this->_updateActiveTab();
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}

return $this is the problem. Use above code to remove Customer Edit Address Tab.
```